# TypoScript condition in frontend context (9.5 LTS, expression syntax) for backend users logged in

Tags: typo3, conditional-statements, typoscript, typo3-9.x

Heyho, I’m playing with the new expression syntax in TYPO3 CMS 9.5 LTS. I'm trying to display something in FE when user has an active BE login. The feature rst suggests:

```
[backend.user.isLoggedIn == true]
...
[END]
```

and it should work?! but does not work and throws:

`TYPO3 Deprecation Notice: The old condition syntax will be removed in TYPO3 v10.0, use the new expression language. Used condition: [backend.user.isLoggedIn === true]`

```
[getTSFE().beUserLogin > 0]
...
[END]
```

works but throws: `TYPO3 Deprecation Notice: Property $TSFE->beUserLogin is not in use anymore as this information is now stored within the backend.user aspect.`

So what’s wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

With TYPO3 version < 9.5.16 the object "backend" is only available in BE (TSconfig).

For frontend (TS Setup) you might use `[getTSFE() && getTSFE().isBackendUserLoggedIn()]`.

Starting with TYPO3 version 9.5.16, which was released on 28.4.2020 and contains the bugfix "Make backend.user conditions in FE work", the following condition can now also be used:

```
[backend.user.isLoggedIn]
```

Comment: Nope. Where exactly are you reading that in TSref?
Just [tested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68790995/6783328) in TYPO3 v.10.4.19 - and it's working.

Comment: I understood it this way, since the parent paragraph says "The values are context related." and there is a separate section "Functions in frontend and backend context". The question was about version 9.

Comment: @JulianHofmann I have now revised my answer, as it actually works in the meantime due to a bug fix.