# TYPO3 10: Disable page when not logged into backend

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

In TYPO3 10 is there a way to disable a page for anyone not logged in to the backend. Prior to Typo3 10, I believe something like this worked:

```
[getTSFE() && getTSFE().isBackendUserLoggedIn() == false]
  page = PAGE
  page.10 = TEXT
  page.10.value = Page disabled
[GLOBAL]
```

But in Typo3 10 this does not work any more because of changes in the TSFE Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 9.5.16/10.4.1, you could use `[backend.user.isLoggedIn]` or `[backend.user.isAdmin]` ([TSref](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Conditions/Index.html#backend-user)) for checking BE user properties.

Maybe it would be a better approach to "hide" the page for unwanted visitors by setting an HTTP auth...

---

Update:

Tested *both* variants. *Both* condition variants are matching in an TYPO3 v10.4.17/10.4.19:

```
page.200 = TEXT
[getTSFE() && getTSFE().isBackendUserLoggedIn() == true]
    page.200.value = BE-User is logged in.
[getTSFE() && getTSFE().isBackendUserLoggedIn() == false]
    page.200.value = BE-User is NOT logged in.
[global]

page.250 = TEXT
page.250.value = <hr />

page.300 = TEXT
page.300.value = BE-User is NOT logged in.
[backend.user.isLoggedIn]
    page.300.value = BE-User is logged in.
[global]
```

**Notice:**
To get this work, your FE and BE must be able to share their session cookie. This means, both must be called with *same* domain (or appropriately configured cookie domain). Be aware with multi-domain instance and the variants with/without "www" ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com) != example.com)

Comment: Unfortunately that does not seem to work for me: Maybe because `[backend.user.isLoggedIn]` it is only available in backend context, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58561042/10133892

Comment: Sure, your BE session is with the same domain or session cookie can be accessed by the FE request?

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem indeed, I have a multidomain setup and the backend runs on a different domain.